# Prolog ERROR out of global stack

Tags: prolog

```
ass(a).
ass(b).
ass(c).

con(c,r).

arg(A, L) :- forall(member(S, L), (ass(S), \+ con(S,A))).
```

If I run `arg(r, [a,b])` it will work but if I run `arg(r,X)` it returns: ERROR out of global stack. I would like it to return `[a,b]`. I understand this is because `L` is unbounded, but how can I fix this.

Comment: If you explained the meaning of the `arg` predicate, that would help.

Comment: @mbratch yes you are right sorry!! I need to find all the atoms which are ass() and that are not in contrary with A.

Comment: @mbratch: Why did you add again tag swi-prolog. There is nothing specific to SWI at all in this question...

Comment: @false sorry, I thought the OP was using an SWI specific predicate but I was mistaken. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

In the predicate:

```
arg(A, L) :- forall(member(S, L), (ass(S), \+ con(S,A))).
```

May have a limitation in your case as described in the SWI Prolog documentation for `forall/2`:

> If your intent is to create variable bindings, the forall/2 control
>   structure is inadequate. Possibly you are looking for `maplist/2`,
>   `findall/3` or `foreach/2`.

So in this case, you may be better off with:

```
arg(A, L) :- findall(S, (ass(S), \+ con(S,A)), L).
```

Which will yield:

```
?- arg(r, X).
X = [a, b].

?- arg(r, [a,b]).
true.

?-
```